# How to reference old column value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that will insert records into the table `OH_PONUMBER_AUDIT` based off of the update of the column `PONUMBER` on the table `REPORDER` but I do not know how to insert records using new and old column values in SQL Server.

I have a trigger similar to this on DB2 so I am assuming the functionality should exist within SQL Server.

Thanks in advance

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[PONUMBER_AUDIT]
ON [DBO].[REPORDER] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE (PONUMBER)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [DBO].[OH_PONUMBER_AUDIT] 
           ([ORDERNUM]
           ,[USER_WHO_CHANGED]
           ,[DATE_CHANGED]
           ,[FIELD_CHARGED]
           ,[OLD_VALUE]
           ,[NEW_VALUE])
            SELECT 
                ORDERNUM, SESSION_USER, GETDATE(), 'PONUMBER', O.PONUMBER, N.PONUMBER 
            FROM 
                [TFW].[DBO].[REPORDER];
    END
END
```

Comment: Keep in mind that UPDATE will evaluate to true if the column is in the update statement. It does NOT evaluate if the previous and new values have changed. Since you are wanting to track changes to that column you should not use the UPDATE check at all. Join inserted and deleted and check that inserted.PONUMBER <> deleted.PONUMBER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` pseudo tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[PONUMBER_AUDIT]
    ON [DBO].[REPORDER] 
    AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (PONUMBER)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO [DBO].[OH_PONUMBER_AUDIT] 
           ([ORDERNUM]
           ,[USER_WHO_CHANGED]
           ,[DATE_CHANGED]
           ,[FIELD_CHARGED]
           ,[OLD_VALUE]
           ,[NEW_VALUE])
        SELECT  I.ORDERNUM, 
                SESSION_USER, 
                GETDATE(), 
                'PONUMBER', 
                D.PONUMBER, 
                I.PONUMBER 
        FROM INSERTED I 
        INNER JOIN DELETED D
            ON I.[ORDERNUM] = D.[ORDERNUM];
    END
END
```

This code assumes that `ORDERNUM` is the primary key of the table.

Comment: I am getting an error incorrect syntax near the keyword session_user

Comment: @OVO yeah, I updated my answer. I removed the alias prefix

Answer (score 1):

Within a TRIGGER you should use `inserted` and `deleted` tables.

Instead of use: `IF UPDATE (PONUMBER)` I'd suggest to use

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT     1 
           FROM       inserted
           INNER JOIN deleted
           ON         inserted.<key_field> = deleted.<key_field>
           WHERE      inserted.PONUMBER <> deleted.PONUMBER)


USE [TFW]
GO 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[PONUMBER_AUDIT]
    ON [DBO].[REPORDER] 
    AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE (PONUMBER)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO [DBO].[OH_PONUMBER_AUDIT] 
           ([ORDERNUM]
           ,[USER_WHO_CHANGED]
           ,[DATE_CHANGED]
           ,[FIELD_CHARGED]
           ,[OLD_VALUE]
           ,[NEW_VALUE])
        SELECT     ORDERNUM, 
                   SESSION_USER, 
                   GETDATE(), 
                   'PONUMBER', 
                   O.PONUMBER, 
                   N.PONUMBER 
        FROM       inserted
        INNER JOIN deleted
        ON         inserted.<KEY_FIELD> = deleted.<KEY_FIELD> 
        WHERE      inserted.PONUMBER <> deleted.PONUMBER

    END
END
```